# Spring Cloud Config Server configuration with local repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I'm trying to set up Spring Cloud Config Server with backend repository (filesystem), but the endpoint(`http://localhost:8888/licensingservice/default`) returns the following:

```
{"name":"licensingservice","profiles":["default"],"label":null,"version":null,"state":null,"propertySources":[]}
```

The Main:

```
@EnableConfigServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConfigServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The application.yml:

```
server:
   port: 8888
spring:
   profiles:
      active: native
    cloud:
       config:
          server:
             native:
                searchLocations: file:///Users/josedavi/Desenvolvimento/WorkSpace/Pessoal/sample-spring-microservices/sample-spring-microservices/config-server/src/main/resources/config
```

The licensingservice.yml:

```
tracer.property: "I AM THE DEFAULT"
spring.jpa.database: "POSTGRESQL"
spring.datasource.platform: "postgres"
spring.jpa.show-sql: "true"
spring.database.driverClassName: "org.postgresql.Driver"
spring.datasource.url: "jdbc:postgresql://database:5432/eagle_eye_local"
spring.datasource.username: "postgres"
spring.datasource.password: "p0stgr@s"
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle: "true"
spring.datasource.validationQuery: "SELECT 1"
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect: "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"
```

[image]

The path of the service config:

```
C:\Users\josedavi\Desenvolvimento\WorkSpace\Pessoal\sample-spring-microservices\sample-spring-microservices\config-server\src\main\resources\config
```

The Project:
https://github.com/jdavid-araujo/sample-spring-microservices

Comment: I have a sample that is working fine. Can you provide a project that recreates the problem? What versions are you using?

Comment: I´m using Spring Boot: 2.1.2 and Spring Cloud: Greenwich. 
The project is in gitHub: https://github.com/jdavid-araujo/sample-spring-microservices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following format in your `application.yml` of config service:

> [classpath:/, classpath:/config, classpath:/config/{application}, classpath:/config/{application}/{profile}]

The above format search locations from `config` folder, next folder with `application` name, `application` name and `profile` respectively.

```
spring:
   profiles:
      active: native
   cloud:
       config:
          server:
             native:
                searchLocations: "[classpath:/, classpath:/config, classpath:/config/{application}, classpath:/config/{application}/{profile}]"
```

Comment: It´s doesn´t work to me. 
I put the project in github: https://github.com/jdavid-araujo/sample-spring-microservices

Comment: I checked your code, you should just copy and paste the above format, you don't need to update anything. Then i will work. @DavidAraujo

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the problem is your `searchLocations` property. The path must reach the `licensingservice` folder itself, and if the server provides configuration for more than one service, you must set the paths for each of them (separated by comma).

Try this way:

```
...
spring:
  ...
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        native:
          searchLocations: file:///C:/Users/josedavi/Desenvolvimento/WorkSpace/Pessoal/sample-spring-microservices/sample-spring-microservices/config-server/src/main/resources/config/licensingservice
```

Alternatively, you can use the relative path:

```
        ...
          searchLocations: classpath:config/licensingservice
```

Also, if you are reading the [Spring Microservices in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/spring-microservices-in-action) book (Chapter 3), you can take a look at the [source code example](https://github.com/carnellj/spmia-chapter3/blob/master/confsvr/src/main/resources/application.yml) itself.

Answer (score 1):

1-

set uri in property (yml) file as below :

**uri**: file:///C:/properties/application.yml

```
  spring:
      application:
        name: Config-Service
      cloud:
        config:
          server:
            git:
    #         uri: https://github.com/xxxx/config-server/
              uri: file:///C:/properties/application.yml
              clone-on-start: true
```

---

2-

another way is to create a git directory in folder that yml file is exist:
[image]

then set config as follows :

```
spring:
  application:
    name: Config-Service
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: file:///C:/properties/
          clone-on-start: true
```

Answer (score 0):

[config server folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t589T.png)

Then in application.yaml file
cloud:
config:
server:
native:
search-locations: "[classpath:/, classpath:/config, classpath:/config/{application}, classpath:/config/{application}/{profile}]"

It will work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

## You need to do two things to make this work:

### 1. Configure the locations from where the config files are loaded

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        native:
          search-locations:
            - classpath:/config # Config files for all microservices
            - classpath:/config/{application} # Config files for specific applications
```

I suggest you don't use absolute paths because it won't work unless it is running on your machine. Better use a relative path to your classpath so that you can also deploy your config server somewhere.

### 2. Activate the `native` profile

The [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html#_file_system_backend) does not explicitely state that the profile is needed, but for me it only worked with multiple `search-locations` when I used the `native` profile.