# Does Spring Cloud Kubernetes Config support local spring config while allowing overrides from ConfigMaps

Tags: java, spring, kubernetes, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I'm comparing Spring Cloud Config with Spring Cloud Kubernetes PropertySource of ConfigMaps. I've managed to do a quick POC with Spring Cloud Config, but I have not done a POC for the Spring Cloud Kubernetes.

What is not 100% clear when reading the documentation of Spring Cloud Kubernetes PropertySource is whether it supports local Spring Config while allowing overrides coming from ConfigMap PropertySource (with embedded yaml). Spring Cloud Config still allows local config but augments it with config from the config server. The documentation does not say either way; but reading all of [Chapter 5](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/docs/current/reference/html/#kubernetes-propertysource-implementations) - it leads me to think you can't use local config; and the bootstrap process fully hands over sourcing config from config maps.

It is also unclear how you would dev locally and easily make use of the config encoded in config maps.

Questions about using spring-cloud-kubernetes config maps as a property source:

1. Does anyone have experience with this that could clarify if local config is supported?
2. How you conveniently consume the same config when developing locally?

Comment: i think this is a duplicate issue look for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54557032/spring-cloud-config-server-configuration-with-local-repository

Comment: Hi Filipe - this question is about Spring Cloud Kubernetes PropertySource supporting a mix of local and external config from config maps. This link above is about Spring Cloud Config - which I have confirmed supports a mix of local config and config from the config-server at a config-client.